# Получить кириллический домен

Tags: javascript, url

Есть сайт (пример) - [http://з-саюоыжаѓхнцч.рф](http://%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8E%D0%BE%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%93%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%87.%D1%80%D1%84), но если перейти на него и получить url с помощью window.location.href, то результат будет что-то вроде такого -

```
http://xn----8sbaxc4bew4bll6byb0e.xn--p1ai/
```

Вопрос, как с помощью js получить оригинальный .рф адрес?

Comment: Держите библиотеку для конвертации https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать метод `decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)`

Подробнее изучить можете здесь [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).